how to create Token account from solana wallet adapter
I want to send the tokens from the frontend, how can I create the ATA account for destination address?

you can use the getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount method from @solana/spl-token package if you are unsure whether the token accounts exist on the receiver side.
let toTokenAccount = await (
        await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            conn,
            signer,
            mint,
            signer.publicKey,
            false,
            "finalized",
            {},
            new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")
        )
    ).address;

On the UI side, the wallet adapter doesn't expose the signer private key or keypair.
You'll need to use the sendTransanction from the useWAllet hook to sign and send your transaction
import { useWallet, useConnection } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";

const { sendTransaction } = useWallet();
const { connection } = useConnection();

let sig = await sendTransaction(TX, connection);



how can I pass signer from frontend, basically Im using solana wallet adapter

Thanks for reply - but how Can i pass address and sign transaction. do you please edit the question? for just creating from frontend using sendTransction.

the method above will use the connected wallet and it's address to sign the transaction.
